# search with multiple values and in multiple fields in php mysql Zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here, I have three multi-select combo boxes namely *department*, *designation* and *Location* where the user can select more than one value in each field. I perform an `OR` operation in the query to display the name of the employee who belongs atleast one of the fields.

This works well if I choose only one department name, designation name and location. If I select more than 1 value,it dosent work. I have to *for-loop* the `WHERE` condition of *department*, *designation* and *location* based on the selected count.
How could I loop only the conditon here so that it becomes `select 'emp_id' from emp_personal' where Department_Id='1' or Department_Id='7' or Designation_Id='6'....`

```
public function listEmployees($searchArray=null, $logEmpId=null,  $formName=null) 
{

$department = $searchArray['Department'];
$designation= $searchArray['Designation'];
$location=$searchArray['Location'];


      $conditions=$this->_db->quoteInto('Department_Id =?', $department);  
      $conditions .= $this->_db->quoteInto('or Designation_Id = ?', $designation);
      $conditions .= $this->_db->quoteInto('or Location_Id = ?', $location);
      $qryEmployees= $this->_db->select()->from(array('En'=>$this->_ehrTables->empJob), array('En.Employee_Id'))->where($conditions)

     ->joinInner(array('E'=>$this->_ehrTables->empPersonal), 'E.Employee_Id = En.Employee_Id', array('Employee_Name'=>new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(E.Emp_First_Name, ' ', E.Emp_Last_Name)")));



 $result = $this->_db->fetchAll($qryEmployees); 
 return $result;


}
```

Comment: *What* doesn't work? Do you get any error messages? Please clarify what your expected outcome is.

Comment: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) .it returns this error if i choose more than one value in any field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use SELECT IN(value1,value2,...)

Comment: What is the cardinality between your entities?